# protected pages

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I got a strange requirment which i have no idea how to work on can you help by giving me some hints how to search about this

We want to provide an intranet site  that shows policies to the employee the

Strange requirement here is 
they want the policies to be viewable and searchable but not savable , not printable (kind of what you get in kindle cloud reader) where you can read the book in your browser but can't copy , save nor print it.

is there any tool that makes this possible ! ?

Comment: what ever you show on a webpage can be copied.you can just make it difficult but not impossible

Comment: In ASP.NET? No. Or do you want to develop also a custom browser which can't copy or view source and must be used for your site? However, even then the user could [fiddle](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) the http traffic.

Comment: @Champ  how amazon is doing this for kindle cloud reader ?!

Comment: @TimSchmelter how amazon is doing this for kindle cloud reader ?!

Answer (score 3):

**This is not really possible.** There is always a way to print or save a webpage. The only thing you can do, is make it harder for novice users.

**Printing:**
create a print.css file, which hides all the content. Example:

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    display: none;  /* hide whole page */
  }
}
```

**Saving**: No real solution, only disabling the right-click is possible. Try this:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

As stated above, both these solutions don't hold back powerusers. Nothing can prevent just making a screenshot.